# Regex to uppercase between delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex that looks for any `$$some_val$$` and replaces the `some_val` with  uppercase letters.

For example the input is:-

```
<p><a href='accept/272/$$id$$'>YES</a></p>
<p>Hi $$FirstName$$ some more text $$date$$ lorem ipsum</p>
<h1>$$club$$</h1>
$$content$$
```

would output:-

```
<p><a href='accept/272/$$ID$$'>YES</a></p>
<p>Hi $$FIRSTNAME$$ some more text $$DATE$$ lorem ipsum</p>
<h1>$$CLUB$$</h1>
$$CONTENT$$
```

at the moment I have the following regex:-

```
var html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\$\$(.*)\$\$", m=> m.Value.ToUpper());
```

but it produces the incorrect result.

```
<p><a href='accept/272/$$ID$$'>YES</a></p>
<p>Hi $$FIRSTNAME$$ SOME MORE TEXT $$DATE$$ lorem ipsum</p>
<h1>$$CLUB$$</h1>
$$CONTENT$$
```

as the `SOME MORE TEXT` is also capitalised between the start and end $$ delimiters.

Please note that $$ might reoccur in a line OR start/end on a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the non-greedy/lazy match quantifier ( `*?` ):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\$\$.*?\$\$");
var input = "this $$is a$$ test of the $$procedure$$";
var output =
     r.Replace(input, m=>m.Value.ToUpper());
```

Comment: Ah greed is my downfall! Thanks will try it out.

Comment: As with all string operations, output will vary according to locale. It may be better to specify the locale (or invariant) in the long-run.

Comment: BTW I just noticed that you don't use `(.*)` but just `.*`, I take it it doesn't matter which I use.

Answer (score 2):

try this , it should works :

```
var html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\$\$(.\w*)\$\$", m=> m.Value.ToUpper());
```

i have test it on : http://rubular.com/r/YRI3WrzXAu

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the lazy `*?` instead of the eager `*`. `*` by itself tries to match as much as possible, `*?` tries to match as little as possible.

```
var html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\$\$(.*?)\$\$", m=> m.Value.ToUpper());
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use a lookahead assertion. For example:

```
var html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\$\$(?:[^$]|\$(?!\$))*\$\$", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
```

This would search for the two dollars, then search for anything that is not a dollar OR a dollar that is not succeeded by another dollar. Greediness in this case would not matter due to the lookahead assertion.

This is a bit more advanced than the dot-star you've been using, so if dot-star works for you, then it may be more realistic to stick with that.